# How do I move AnyLogic agents from one space to another?

Tags: anylogic, agent, spaces

In my AnyLogic model, *Container* agents are moved around within the *Main* agent to various locations.

Main contains several instances of *Block* agents at specific locations. *Block* contains a multi-bridge overhead crane which is supposed to pick up the *Container* and move it to local storage.

When the *Container* is placed at an Attractor within range of the *Block*'s crane, a process inside the *Block* is called.
This process contains Entry, MoveByCrane, and Exit blocks.
In the MoveByCrane block, at the seize step, AnyLogic is giving me the following error:

```
Exception during discrete event execution
root.blocks[0].moveContainerIn.seize:
The agent root.containers[0] and the crane com.anylogic.engine.markup.OverheadCrane@50b7349f have different spaces
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.MHLBlock_xjal.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.SeizeCrane.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.SeizeCrane.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.SeizeCrane.getHookDestinationPoint(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.SeizeCrane.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.SeizeCrane.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.SeizeCrane$1.onEnter(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay$9.onEnter(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.receiveImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.forwardReadyEntityNotification(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.action(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.AsynchronousExecutor_xjal$a.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler$b.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.hi(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.f(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$b.run(Unknown Source)
```

All of the Block agents are located at different coordinates within main. They each have their own coordinate reference/origin. (The location (0,0) in the block is not the same as (0,0) in main.) Is this the meaning of the term "spaces" in the error message?

Is there a way to move an agent from one space to another?

Should I remove (sink) the agent from one space and create a new one in the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Easiest way is to use `Enter` and `Exit` blocks in `Main` and your agent types and send the agents across different spaces this way. In the `Enter` properties, specify a location within the agent type and it will make your arriving agent "switch" to the new space.

If you are not using process modelling blocks, you need to call `setEnvironment()` and then define the agent location within its new environment using `setLocation(...)`